# Dual Django stack on same database

Tags: python, django, session, orm, django-socialauth

We have just finished migrating our very old Django 1.6 (with South)/ Python 2 app to a new well-maintained OS running a well-maintained version of PostgreSQL
There were several attempts to upgrade the Django app code, but it's so old it relies on libraries that are no longer supported or have a new version with a radically changed APIs.
We finally settled to copying the entire virtual environment and run old code on old libraries. It actually works just fine internally.

However, third party APIs have moved on and don't support old libraries anymore. Not that they were working on the old server. **So we would like to create a new Django 5 / Python 3** stack that would cover the following

- Social login
- Modern Django Rest framework
- A new frontend with a modern framework, eventually

Now, running two nginx server {} or location {} with separate gunicorns doesn't scare me but I'm wondering:

- *can the two stacks use the same database ?*
- *can I interact with sessions using one stack and expect the other to follow ?*
- *how can I evolve the model properly on both stacks ?*